Is the dark energy equation of state constant over time?
There are plenty of questions and answers here about what the dark energy equation of state (EoS) parameter $w_{de}$ is and, its impact on the future of the Universe, if if happens to be $w_{de} = -1, >-1$ or $<-1$.
However (at the risk of a trivial question), you can write: $w_{de}(z)$ where $z$ is the redshift.
Question: For the consensus EoS (cosmological constant) $\Lambda=-1$ does this mean $w_{de}(z)=-1$, no matter the $z$ i.e. through the whole history of the Universe, not just $w_0=-1$?
I guess a follow on to the above question is - what viable models are there where the dark energy EoS actually varies, and what would that even mean?

For a cosmological constant, $w=-1$ always. With dynamical dark energy models, $w$ generally varies with time. For cosmology experiments it is conventional to parametrize
$$w(a) = w_0 + w_a(1-a)$$
where $a=1/(1+z)$ is the scale factor. Although this is just a phenomenological description, it was shown to map quite accurately to the predictions of dynamical dark energy models (see Linder, 2003; de Putter & Linder, 2008).
Recent news in the cosmology community is that the DESI Collaboration reports a significant statistical preference for this "$w_0w_a$" time-varying description over the constant equation of state (see DESI 2024 VI). As they write in the press release, they are

seeing some potentially interesting differences that could indicate that dark energy is evolving with time. Those may or may not go away with more data, so we’re excited to start analyzing our three-year dataset soon.

